# anaconda navigator not opening with error active.bat

Tags: python, anaconda

so i installed anaconda graphical installer but when i searched for `anaconda-navigator` on my anaconda prompt it did not open instead it showed this message 
`'C:\Users\RAM\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` 
I do not know what does this mean please help me fix this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do this

1. Install/Delete everything related to Python/Anaconda
2. Install the desired version of **miniConda** from  https://conda.io/miniconda.html
3. Open miniConda prompt and `conda install anaconda=5.1` or 5.0.1 version